# How can I retrieve the phone number in selenium?

Tags: python, selenium, xpath

```
import json
from io import StringIO
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from requests_html import HTMLSession
import time
from selenium import webdriver
import requests
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
import colorama
from colorama import Fore, Back, Style
colorama.init(autoreset = False)
import selenium
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains

PATH = "C:\Program Files (x86)\chromedriver.exe"
chrome_options = Options()
chrome_options.add_experimental_option('excludeSwitches', ['enable-logging'])
driver = webdriver.Chrome(PATH, options = chrome_options)
# driver.minimize_window()

for b in range(3):

    url = "https://www.healthgrades.com/usearch?what=Marriage%20%26%20Family%20Therapy&entityCode=PS303&where=CA&pageNum={}&sort.provider=bestmatch&state=CA".format(b+1)

    driver.implicitly_wait(50)
    driver.get(url)
    wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 500)
    button = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//a[@class = 'provider-name__lnk']")
    length =  len(driver.find_elements(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "a[data-qa-target='provider-details-provider-name']"))

    j = 0
    for i in range(length):
        elements = driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, "//a[@data-qa-target='provider-details-provider-name']")
        print(elements[j].text)
        # ActionChains(driver).move_to_element(elements[j].find_element_by_xpath(".//ancestor::div[contains(@class,'card-summary')]/following-sibling::div[contains(@class,'card-cta')]/a")).click().perform()
        button.click()

        time.sleep(2)
        phone = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//a[@class='toggle-phone-number-button']")
        print(phone.text)
        # print(wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//a[@class='click-to-call-button-secondary hg-track mobile-click-to-call']"))).text)
        driver.execute_script("window.history.go(-1)")
        time.sleep(2)
        j = j + 1
```

Hey guys, Someone on this platform already helped me this code, but I expanded it. What it should do: scrape the name of the therapists, click on their link, extract the phone number, go back to first website, repeat. What it does: scrapes the name, clicks on the link. It can't find the phone number. I am maybe using an wrong ID, because it returns the error "a NON TYPE has no attribute text". Can anyone help me fix the code in line 19 , so it prints the phone number? Any help much appreciated.

Comment: Please post the complete code. (Including the imports)

Comment: @Ram I posted the imports I used

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to extract the `phone number` with below line. If this line does not give the phone number, you need to switch the focus to other window and then try to extract details.

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@class='summary-standard-button-row-mobile']/a").get_attribute("innerText")
```

This is the complete code I have tried:

```
driver.implicitly_wait(10)
driver.get("https://www.healthgrades.com/usearch?what=Marriage%20%26%20Family%20Therapy&entityCode=PS303&where=CA&pageNum=1&sort.provider=bestmatch&state=CA")
for page in range(2,4):
    time.sleep(5)
    length = len(driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//a[@data-qa-target='provider-details-provider-name']"))
    for i in range(length):
        elements = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//a[@data-qa-target='provider-details-provider-name']")
        elements[i].click()
        handles = driver.window_handles
        driver.switch_to.window(handles[1])
        time.sleep(1)
        print(driver.find_element_by_tag_name("h1").get_attribute("innerText"))
        try:
            print(driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@class='summary-standard-button-row-mobile']/a").get_attribute("innerText"))
        except Exception as e:
            print("No Contact Details")
            pass
        driver.close()
        driver.switch_to.window(handles[0])
        time.sleep(1)
    driver.find_element_by_xpath("//a[text()='{}']".format(page)).click()
```

Output:

```
Noe Gutierrez, MSW
(760) 385-3959
Richard Vogel, LMFT
(949) 690-6846
Rachel Sievers, LMFT
(559) 901-2836
...
```

Comment: The URL I used : [Link](https://www.healthgrades.com/usearch?what=Marriage%20%26%20Family%20Therapy&entityCode=PS303&where=CA&pageNum=1&sort.provider=bestmatch&state=CA)

Comment: Thank you for the resonse but I pasted your line in my "phone" variable and it dint work aswell. Ideas?

Comment: @AdrianReichert - Whats happening, you are getting error or not getting any output.

Comment: I am getting an error that it cannot find your xpath

Comment: @AdrianReichert - Can you please copy paste the error. Did you switch to other window?

Comment: selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//div[@class='summary-standard-button-row-mobile']/a"}

Comment: @AdrianReichert - You need to switch to other window. I have updated my answer with complete code. Do check once.

Comment: thx it worked, bu now i want to switch to the next page and do the same.

Comment: @AdrianReichert - Updated code again. Instead of optimizing the URL, I am performing clicking on page numbers.

Answer (score 1):

Few things, looks like locators you have to change, also I do not see back button in automation window :

**Code :**

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome(driver_path)
driver.maximize_window()
driver.implicitly_wait(5)
#driver.get("https://www.finq.com/en/login")
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)

current_windows_handle = driver.current_window_handle
for b in range(1, 4):
    driver.switch_to.window(current_windows_handle)
    url = "https://www.healthgrades.com/usearch?what=Marriage%20%26%20Family%20Therapy&entityCode=PS303&where=CA&pageNum={}&sort.provider=bestmatch&state=CA".format(b)
    driver.get(url)
    try:
        if len(driver.find_elements(By.ID, "onetrust-accept-btn-handler")) > 0:
            wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID, "onetrust-accept-btn-handler"))).click()
        else:
            print("pop up was not visible")
    except:
        pass

    length =  len(driver.find_elements(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "a[data-qa-target='provider-details-provider-name']"))

    j = 0

    for i in range(length):
        driver.switch_to.window(current_windows_handle)
        elements = driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, "//a[@data-qa-target='provider-details-provider-name']")
        print(elements[j].text)
        ActionChains(driver).move_to_element(elements[j]).click().perform()
        time.sleep(2)
        driver.switch_to.window(driver.window_handles[1])
        try:
            if len(driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, "//a[@class='toggle-phone-number-button']")) > 0 :
                 phone = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//a[@class='toggle-phone-number-button']")
                 print(phone.text)
            else:
                print("Phone number was not available")
        except:
            pass
        driver.close()
        time.sleep(2)
        j = j + 1
        print(j)
```

**Output :**

```
"C:\Program Files\Python39\python.exe" C:/Users/panabh02/PycharmProjects/SeleniumSO/Chrome.py
Noe Gutierrez, MSW
(760) 385-3959
1
Richard Vogel, LMFT
(949) 690-6846
2
Rachel Sievers, LMFT
(559) 901-2836
3
Luisa Contreras, LMFT
(657) 888-3222
4
Lauren Reminger, MA
(951) 541-1898
5
Dr. Peter Robbins, PHD
(800) 998-6329
6
Ernesto Segismundo, LMFT
(909) 247-8820
7
Crystal Guzman, LMFT
(818) 927-0478
8
Claudia Franzosi, MFT
(619) 246-6700
9
Dr. Irving Croshier, PHD
(818) 710-1266
10
Dr. Richard Zahn, PSY.D
(916) 792-7229
11
Danielle Duran, LMFT
(559) 737-8317
12
Amie Lowery-Luyties, MFT
(310) 494-6587
13
Sherry Johnson, LMFT
(408) 510-4848
14
Rachel McDermott, LMFT
(559) 280-5756
15
Scott Barrella, MSW
(805) 390-6384
16
Ella Begelfor, MFT
(818) 207-1191
17
Dr. Gilbert Chalepas, PSY.D
(310) 500-8442
18
Katki Windsor, LMFT
(408) 471-8536
19
Tara Boerner, LMFT
(818) 924-3960
20
Chad Medlin, LMFT
(805) 746-3180
21
David Coolidge, MA
(916) 608-0714
22
Lissette Gomez, LMFT
(714) 290-1578
1
Wendy Talley, LCSW
(310) 242-6112
2
Lance Ferris, LCSW
(530) 592-7847
3
Jo Ellen Fletcher, LMFT
Phone number was not available
4
Dr. Judith Bucholtz, PHD
(310) 826-1141
5
Angie Nicholas, LMFT
(209) 224-4994
6
Maryam Jamili, LMFT
(949) 735-0500
7
Stephanie Carson, LMFT
(909) 364-1104
8
Betsy Sansby, LMFT
(952) 221-6752
9
Aida Vazin, MAMFT
(949) 872-3926
10
Dr. Wendy O'Connor, PSY.D
(310) 712-1230
11
Chelsea Crow-Fuentes, MA
(949) 484-5008
12
Marymargaret Parker, LMFT
(661) 259-4620
13
Kenton Lane, LMFT
(310) 968-1608
14
Catherine Chambliss, MFT
(310) 303-9132
15
DeAnn Richter, MFT
(714) 396-7776
16
Teje Aliberti, MA
(909) 752-0021
17
Katerra Davis, LMFT
(760) 705-3373
18
Dr. Robert Jaffe, PHD
(818) 906-7079
19
Monica Cervantes, LCSW
(949) 302-8952
20
Behnam Keyvan, MFT
(818) 448-2753
21
Hanouf Alahmari, LMFT
Phone number was not available
22

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Comment: thanks for the response but it returns an error sadly : "from unknown error: web view not found"

Comment: thx, but it only scrapes the phone number of the first 3 people.

Comment: weird, I am getting other results than you.

Comment: yeah I am sure haha i might have used one of your old solutions maybe?

Answer (score 1):

Data is generating with the help of backdoor with api calls. Here I'm getting working output:

CODE:

```
import requests
import pandas as pd

params = {
    'where': 'CA',
    'sessionId': 'S63e7',
    'requestId': 'R1a5829bce167793b',
    'sort.provider': 'bestmatch',
    'what': 'Marriage & Family Therapy',
    'highlight': 'Marriage & Family Therapy',
    'entityCode': 'PS303',
    'code': 'PS303',
    'category': 'provider',
    'cid': '',
    'hgTrace': 'false',
    'isPsr': 'false',
    'isFsr': 'false',
    'isFirstRequest': 'true',
    'pageNum': '2'
  
   
    
}

headers = {
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/92.0.4515.107 Safari/537.36'
}


def main(url):
    with requests.Session() as req:
        req.headers.update(headers)
        elit = []
        r = req.get(url, params=params)
        for item in r.json()['search']['searchResults']['provider']['results']:
            elit.append(item['displayOffice']['phoneNumbers'][0])

        df = pd.DataFrame(elit, columns=["phoneNumber"])
        print(df)


main(
    'https://www.healthgrades.com/api3/usearch')
```

OUTPUT:

```
  phoneNumber
0   (310) 303-9132
1   (714) 396-7776
2   (909) 752-0021
3   (760) 705-3373
4   (818) 906-7079
5   (949) 302-8952
6   (818) 448-2753
7   (424) 361-9895
8   (530) 541-6696
9   (530) 220-3433
10  (310) 713-6093
11  (909) 353-7080
12  (415) 686-9749
13  (626) 226-7326
14  (408) 981-4224
15  (415) 927-2108
16  (818) 600-2086
17  (818) 416-1110
18  (805) 242-4604
19  (949) 533-0665
20  (310) 709-1612
21  (415) 413-8086
22  (310) 458-3333
23  (951) 777-8176
24  (559) 432-5805
25  (619) 609-9863
26  (858) 717-4196
27  (415) 562-4156
28  (925) 399-1177
29  (818) 706-0040
30  (310) 795-8335
31  (213) 422-9929
32  (714) 446-5830
33  (661) 383-2252
34  (888) 787-1767
35  (510) 516-3188
```